# Which is the most gentle way to end a ssh session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

So far, I already know there are many ways to end a ssh session and disconnect from remote server. Assume under the environment of bash.

- Bash built-in command exit

  `$ exit`
- Bash built-in command logout

  `$ logout`
- Keyboard shortcut Control + D
- External command `fuser`

  `$ fuser -k /dev/pts/[n]`
- Get sshd process id for current user then kill this process

Can anyone explain what's the difference between these commands? Personally Ctrl + D is my favorite one, because it's the fastest one.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`CTRL + d` causes a `logout`. `logout` causes an `exit`. `exit` on its own is different only because it allows you to specify a non-zero exit code in case it's needed. So the first 3 options are equivalent.

Killing ssh, or the terminal will just break the connection. I'm not sure what you're going for with "gentle", but that is not it.

Assuming that by gentle you meant closing connections without errors on either side, just keep using `CTRL + d`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another "gentle" way to exit.
By using escaping character.

[How do I exit an ssh connection](https://superuser.com/questions/467398/how-do-i-exit-an-ssh-connection)

In this post shows the way to do it, just dig it.

Comment: If you think of `~.` that is completely different way of disconnecting from server iirc.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: In my case, it is a router ssh connection, which shows a full screen selective program and no function as exit. Maybe it's a good time of using escape character?